# Looping through Control Names and hiding all controls that contain the right number within a frame

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I am trying to do is on a Word Userform, if I select a number in a combo box (cb_CountCohorts) (options are 1-10) then any control (option button or textbox that contains that number +1 (so if I select 5, those controls that have 6-10) will not be visible.

With that being said, I did get it to work but I know that it is not efficient.
Below is the beginning but I realize for each case, there would have to be 10 more sets of what you see below times 10 different If statements.  Is there a way to say something like if cb_Countcohrts ="1" find all controls in this frame that does not contain Cohort 1 and hide it...if cb_countcohorts ="5" then hide everything that contains cohort 6, 7, 8, 9, 10?  Thanks in advance for all and any help

```
Private Sub cb_CountCohorts_Change()

If cb_CountCohorts = "1" Then
txt_cohort1.Visible = True
txt_cohort2.Visible = False
txt_cohort3.Visible = False
txt_cohort4.Visible = False
txt_cohort5.Visible = False
txt_cohort6.Visible = False
txt_cohort7.Visible = False
txt_cohort8.Visible = False
txt_cohort9.Visible = False
txt_cohort10.Visible = False
```

I tried this too but it doesnt seem to work like I want either

```
Private Sub cb_CountCohorts_Change()
  For i = 2 To 10
  Set VarText = frm_master.Controls("txt_cohort" & i)
  If cb_CountCohorts.Value > VarText.Value Then
    VarText.Visible = False
  End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub cb_CountCohorts_Change()
    Dim v As Long, i As Long

    v = CLng(cb_CountCohorts.Value)
    For i = 2 To 10
        Me.Controls("txt_cohort" & i).Visible = (i <= v)
        'any other controls here....
    Next i

End Sub
```

If you want something generic for all controls (assuming a consistent naming convention) -

```
Private Sub cb_CountCohorts_Change()
    Dim v As Long, c, i As Long, arr

    v = CLng(cb_CountCohorts.Value)

    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If c.Name Like "txt_cohort#*" Then
            arr = Split(c.Name, "_")
            i = CLng(Replace(arr(1), "txt_cohort", ""))
            c.Visible = (i <= v)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

...basically expanded from Robert's suggestion

Comment: Is there a way to do this where it would hide the control if txt_cohort was part of the name...for example I have a txt_cohort1 textbox and a txt_cohort1_pay1....is there a way to hide both with one line?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should work:

```
Dim c As Control

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If InStr(TypeName(c),"cohort") Then
        c.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ok I saw this somewhere else...(thank you!) I guess I am still so new that I didnt know how to string it together since I will do a if statement for the cb_CountCohort seeing if it equaled a number 1-10 and then an Instr to see if it contained a key word/number in the string, then would have to hide everything that was above that number.  Am I overthinking it?